# I want to have two different forms for two pages

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to have a different forms for the `identity.tpl` page and `registration.tpl`.
But the two references on the same form page `customer-form.tpl`.
How can I do ?

My form is static, it works perfectly for the registration.tpl page.

**custom-form.tpl :**

```
{include file='_partials/form-errors.tpl' errors=$errors['']}

<form action="{$action}" id="customer-form" class="js-customer-form" method="post">
  <section>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-15">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="">
          Civilité  <sup class="c-warning">*</sub>
          </label>
          <label class="ml-60 mr-20" for="">
            <input  name="id_gender"
            type="radio"
            value="1">
            Monsieur
          </label>
          <label for="">
            <input  name="id_gender"
            type="radio"
            value="2">
            Madame
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 plr-0 ">
            <label for="">
              Nom  <sup class="c-warning">*</sub>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input name="lastname" type="text" value="" required>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 plr-0 ">
              <label for="">
                Prénom  <sup class="c-warning">*</sub>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="firstname" type="text" value="" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row obligatory">
              <label for=""><sup>*</sup>Champs obligatoires</label>
            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="col-md-6 pt-55">

              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 plr-0 ">
                  <label for="">
                    Adresse e-mail  <sup class="c-warning">*</sub>
                    </label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input name="email" type="email" value="" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-4 plr-0 ">
                    <label for="">
                      Mot de passe  <sup class="c-warning">*</sub>
                      </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input
                      name="password"
                      type="password"
                      value=""
                      required    >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 plr-0 ">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 ml-10">
                      <label for="">
                        <input
                        name="newsletter"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value="1">
                        S’inscrire à la newsletter
                      </label>
                      <!-- <input class="mt-10" type="submit" value="S'INSCRIRE"> -->

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <footer class="form-footer clearfix">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitCreate" value="1">
                    {block "form_buttons"}
                    <button class="btn form-control-submit pull-xs-right" data-link-action="save-customer" type="submit">
                      S'INSCRIRE
                    </button>
                    {/block}
                  </footer>
                </div>

            </section>



          </form>
```

**identity.tpl :**

```
{extends 'customer/page.tpl'}

{block name='page_content'}
  <div class="container container-id container-perso">
      <h2 class="legal">{l s='Your personal information'}</h2>

      {render file='customer/_partials/customer-form.tpl' ui=$customer_form}
  </div>
{/block}
```

**identity.tpl :**

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='page_header_container'}{/block}

{block name='page_content_container'}
{hook h="displaySliderImg"}

<div class="container container-id container-user">
  {block name='register_form_container'}
  <h2 class="legal">{l s='Create an account'}</h2>
  <p class="text-center mt-10">Remplissez les informations ci-dessous.</p>

  <div class="row bg-grey ptb-30 plr-50 mt-90" id="registration">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            {$hook_create_account_top nofilter}
            <section class="register-form">
              {render file='customer/_partials/customer-form.tpl' ui=$register_form}
            </section>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <p>{l s='Already have an account?'} <a href="{$urls.pages.authentication}">{l s='Log in instead!'}</a></p>
{/block}
</div>
{/block}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy all content from `customer-form.tpl` to `identity.tpl` and `registration.tpl` and then make your modifications.
As advice, you should make some changes in corresponding front controller and model object too, because it has validation based on current `customer-form.tpl` fields. Code should be something like this:

```
{render file='customer/_partials/form-that-you-want.tpl' ui=$form-that-you-want}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect `identity.tpl` to another form?

Comment: Yes it is. You could include other TPL than `customer-form.tpl` inside your `identity.tpl`. But you should be carefull, because you are customizing your template and an update or change of template in the future could crash your shop if all changed files are not compatible.

Comment: How should I go about it?

Comment: If you want to redirect to identity.tpl or another template, depending on some condition, you can override function `initContent` at `controllers/front/IdentityController.php`

Answer (score 0):

In PrestaShop each page has a unique value and this value can be fetched using the following code:

```
$this->context->smarty->smarty->tpl_vars['page']->value['page_name']
```

You will get a different value from above variable on Identity and Registration page, you can pass the value of above variable through Smarty and add a condition in 'custom-form.tpl'